# How to validate associated models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I've got `Product` and `Category` models in my application. A product can belong to only one category. These are shown within a drop down list in the "New Product" form.

What I would like to do is that when I create a new product, the app validates the category as well. How can I do that using associated model validations?

Thanks in advance.

Leo

Comment: What would you validate ? When you save a new Product, you don't save any Category I guess ? So what would be the Category validation about ?

Comment: I want to validate the category_id field of the Product model in the view Products/add.ctp.
when there is no categories in the categories table the drop down is empty and this cause a sql error.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would define the validation rules in each Model (Product and Category) that applies to that model.

Answer (score 0):

You should place a validate variable in your Product this way:

```
  // declares a package for a class
    App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Product extends AppModel {

    // validate
    $validate = array(
        'category_id' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => __('You should select a category'),
        ),

    );
}
```